# Any setting to keep minimized running notebooks in the icon tray instead of the taskbar?

Tags: front-end, windows

I have a computation I'd like to keep running in the background without it taking up task-bar space.

I'm using Windows 7 on that machine.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue using the [RBTray utility](http://rbtray.sourceforge.net/).

While this is running, a right-click to the minimize icon of a window will minimize it to the icon-tray instead of the taskbar.